# U-Boot: is it possible to implement bootcount using a SPI EEPROM?

Tags: embedded, u-boot

I'm referring to the [u-boot bootcount/Kconfig](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/v2021.04/drivers/bootcount/Kconfig) for options to implement a boot counter.  Options include `DM_BOOTCOUNT_SPI_FLASH` and `DM_BOOTCOUNT_I2C_EEPROM`.  As it happens we will have a SPI EEPROM like the AT 93c64.  Can u-boot work via a SPI EEPROM?

Comment: Probably not via the option, but adding your own bootcount code to your initialization routine seems like an easy thing to do. You could even make a generic approach and suggest a patch.